# IONIC Framework Scroll issues in List

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I am using simple list view of ionic framework it works fine in some devices and some devices it hides the scroll bar. User can not scroll at all in some devices. Many of the users are facing same problem and they have discussed it [here](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/bug-overflow-scroll-not-working-in-beta-12-beta13/9514/36).

To reproduce the same issue

create app with

`ionic start scrollTest sidemenu`

-Modified "PlaylistsCtrl" Controller to be:

```
.controller('PlaylistsCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.playlists = [
      { title: 'Reggae', id: 1 },
      { title: 'Chill', id: 2 },
      { title: 'Dubstep', id: 3 },
      { title: 'Indie', id: 4 },
      { title: 'Rap', id: 5 },
      { title: 'Cowbell', id: 6 },
      { title: 'Breaks', id: 7 },
      { title: 'Jungle', id: 8 },
      { title: 'Drum & Bass', id: 9 },
      { title: 'Classics', id: 10 },
      { title: 'Blah', id: 11 },
      { title: 'Foo', id: 12 },
      { title: 'Bar', id: 13 },
      { title: 'House', id: 14 },
      { title: 'Trance', id: 15 },
      { title: 'EDM', id: 15 },
      { title: 'Country', id: 16 },
      { title: 'Rock', id: 17 }
    ];
  })
```

-Set overflow-scroll to true in playlists.html:

`<ion-content class="has-header" overflow-scroll="true">...`

-Launch app on device:

`ionic run android`

... and once it starts, the init view (playlists) does not scroll...

Any one can help me out how to deal with this issue it will be great, as we can not launch the application without solving this bug.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Use this ionic js:**

```
<script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

**Remove** overflow-scroll="true" in

```
<ion-content class="has-header" overflow-scroll="true">
```

**Add this code in app.js**

```
if(ionic.Platform.isAndroid())
    $ionicConfigProvider.scrolling.jsScrolling(false);
```

**Eg:**

```
angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic']).config(function($ionicConfigProvider)   {
    if (ionic.Platform.isAndroid())
       $ionicConfigProvider.scrolling.jsScrolling(false);
     })
```

the above code does same things as overflow-scroll="true" do . and it use native scroll instead of jsScroll

Comment: hi...@boobalan... my problem is `jsScrolling(false)` doesn't work  with iOS devices at all.... is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

In my case with **ionic 1.1.0** the only way to scroll in **ios8-9(and safari)** is using [ion-scroll](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionScroll/) instead ionic-content:

```
<ion-scroll scrollbar-y="false" direction="y" style="height:92%">
```

To me appear that this attribute is required. Without it the trick doesn't work. Another thing.. pay attention to the option **data-tap-disabled="true"** that can be written in some parents of your element.

It must be removed or setted to false:

```
data-tap-disabled="true"
```

On ion-scroll the attribute overflow-scroll doesn't exist and the attribute scroll is setted to true.